# Pandas how to locate by category from aggregate?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data that I've binned, then grouped by bin, counted entries in each bin with `.count` and queried for a number of samples per bin

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

A = np.random.random(10000)
bins = np.arange(0, max(A), 0.03)

data_bins = pd.cut(A, bins = bins, precision = 100)

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": A,
                   "bin":  data_bins})\
    .sort_values(by = ["bin"])\
    .reset_index(drop = True)\
    .dropna()

print(df.head())

# For example, only take bins with more than 310 entries in each
valid_bins = df.groupby("bin")[["A"]].count().query("A > 310")

print(valid_bins)
```

So now I know which bins to look for with `valid_bins` in my large dataset. Now, how do I locate only these bins in the original `df`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for `Series` with same size as original `DataFrame`, so is possible filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.groupby("bin")["A"].transform('count') > 310]
```

Or use slowier solution with [filtration](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration):

```
df1 = df.groupby("bin").filter(lambda x: x["A"].count() > 310)

print(df1.head())
            A           bin
674  0.080059  (0.06, 0.09]
675  0.074179  (0.06, 0.09]
676  0.062529  (0.06, 0.09]
677  0.087312  (0.06, 0.09]
678  0.070065  (0.06, 0.09]
```